# detect the right mouse click + the refresh

Tags: jquery, html

Is there a way to detect a right mouse click then refresh.

To detect a right mouse click I use:

```
jQuery(document).on("mousedown",myFunction); 

function myFunction(e){
...
if( e.button == 2 ) { 

}
}
```

In myFunction I wanna detect "refresh" item is clicked.

I use IE browser.[image]

Comment: What if the user hits F5 or Ctrl+R to refresh?

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};

  $(document).mousedown(function(e){ 
    if( e.button == 2 ) { 
      window.location.reload();
      return false; 
    } 
    return true; 
  }); 
});
```

Comment: I like: document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;}; +1
It solves a part of my problem :)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`event.which == 3` shows that it is a right click

```
$('#element').mousedown(function(event) {
    switch (event.which) {        
        case 3:
            location.reload();
            break;
    }
});
```

For more information [SEE](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) and [JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ricksmarty/Mqg9Z/)

Comment: After I detect a right mouse click, I wanna click the refresh item.
How can I detect that the refresh item is clicked?

Comment: You should also prevent the default behaviour of right clicking.

document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};

Comment: I think you want to look for the `window.onunload` since the page will be refreshing. Your requirements are not crystal clear, if you would like to clarify some more ....

Comment: @lolita see http://vinodvillain1986.blogspot.in/2013/03/disable-refresh-button-on-browser-using.html

Comment: @RakeshShetty you should put it into some fiddle and shows that it works. I doubt that it just disables the **F5** key, while user can always use mouse to refresh the page (even he can use the Refresh button of the browser).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code:

```
$("#refresh").mousedown(function(e) { if (e.which === 3) { 
     alert('element with id "refresh" clicked!');
 } });
```

Comment: The e.which checks what button do you click

Comment: You should also prevent the default behaviour of right clicking. document.oncontextmenu = function() {return false;};

Comment: I don't have an element with the id='refresh' but I wanna click the refresh item after clicking the right button of the mouse.